# Is there an easy way to implement Bottom player in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Is there any easy way to implement bottom player in flutter?
I have tried with the Bottom navigation bar along with the routing, But that doesn't work,
So Can anybody please help me to sort it out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please be more specific on why isn't bottom navigation bar working out for you

Comment: What do you mean by a bottom player? Your question needs clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BottomSheet class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) or if you want to use an external package there is a package called [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel). You can place you player inside these components.